# Why can't I add a user as friend in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been trying to add a user to my friends list on League of Legends. I know his username and I know his summoner name, but the game stubbornly insist they do not exist. This isn't limited to friendship: even the profile page doesn't load.

What's going on? Is it failing because he's offline, or is it failing because he's in a different region than me?

Comment: You won't be able to add someone as a friend if they are from a different region. Thats about the only reason I can think of as to why this is happening to you, other than the servers pulling a wobbly. You could probably check on http://www.lolbase.net/search too.

Comment: @danixd You should probably post that as an answer. I happen to be said friend, and we do happen to be in different regions. That said, lolbase.net also requires the user to have submitted log files.

Comment: @Grace Note Oh right, thanks for clearing up the lolbase thing, I will make an answer then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately players in different regions will not be able to interact with each other in any way. This includes:

- Playing games together
- Viewing profiles
- Adding them to friends list
- Any form of in game chat.

Currently (*the end of Season 1*) - the only option you have is to start a new account in the same region as your friend.

There is no way to transfer your account from one region to another. *This may change in the future†*, however I'd imagine that it would incur a charge in the form of Riot Points.

If you decide to create a new account, bare in mind that playing in the wrong region could also give you in game [latency issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28video_gaming%29), which will have a negative impact on your gaming experience, depending on the level of the problem.

> † 
>   http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=165067&page=7
>
> Jesse Perring
>
> Customer Support Specialist
>
> 09-13-2010, 11:40 AM All of the
>   feedback is always greatly
>   appreciated. We are definitely paying
>   attention. Unfortunately, right now
>   it's just not possible from a
>   technical standpoint to transfer any
>   account content, between two servers,
>   or even on one server. It's something
>   we're thinking about for the future,
>   but we can't be sure if or when it
>   will be available yet.

Comment: Also, [there's this Gaming question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22762/transfer-league-of-legends-account) on transfer. Hopefully there will be some option to transfer.

Comment: On an unrelated note, might I suggest an obelisk (†) if you want to make an annotation without the text being italicized?

Comment: Ha yes that works, thanks. Asterix's cause all sorts of issues!

Comment: I clearly remember that my friend was able to transfer his American LoL account to a Singapore one. I'll try to ask him how he did it.

Comment: @bckbck I am sure this is not true, but I am happy to get proven wrong. Do you have any more details?

Answer (score 0):

you need to run as admintrator cmds type in "Computer.LolLauncherGarena.ErrorFriendReport = 100" And There you go!

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Your answer is a little barebones and could probably use a little more clarification! Specifically, the Garena client only applies to certain regions. If you could specify the region this applies to and perhaps go into detail about what the result of this answer is, you would have a great answer here!